# How to configure rust oauth2 for MSAL2 (TenantId) in Azure

Tags: azure, rust, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use the [rust package oauth2](https://docs.rs/oauth2/latest/oauth2/index.html) (4.2.0) to sso with azure msal 2 .
Azure prevents using the 'common' endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, which is specified in the [provided MS Graph example](https://github.com/ramosbugs/oauth2-rs/blob/main/examples/msgraph.rs)

Instead, the endpoint should look like: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

How would I adapt the setup accordingly?

Comment: What have you tried? The [`oauth2` documentation](https://docs.rs/oauth2/latest/oauth2/index.html#getting-started-authorization-code-grant-w-pkce) shows how to specify the authorization URL.

Comment: I have tried the example MS Graph stated in the oauth2 documentation, it fails due to situation described above.

In the documentation neither async nor sync example includes a TenantId which is needed to address the endpoint correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adapting the connection string (ie retrieve a newly created env variable `TENANT_ID`, concatenate strings to create the desired url)